# How to handle two api calls in react-typescript ant-design

Tags: antd, react-typescript

```
interface SingleCustomerShipmentData {
    _id: string;
    shipping_type: string;
    origin_port_city: string;
    destination_port_city: string;
    shipment_pickup_date: string;
}

interface SingleCustomerData {
    id: string;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    email: string;
    phone: string;
    Avatar: string;
}

const columns: ColumnsType<SingleCustomerShipmentData> = [
    {
        title: 'Shipment Type',
        dataIndex: 'shipping_type',
        key: 'shipping_type',
        render: (shipping_type, data) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <img className='customers-avatar' src={data.Avatar} alt="" />
                    {shipping_type}
                </div>
            )
        },
    },
    {
        title: 'Origin',
        dataIndex: 'origin_port_city',
        key: 'origin_port_city',
    },
    {
        title: 'Destination',
        dataIndex: 'destination_port_city',
        key: 'destination_port_city',
    },
    {
        title: 'Shipment Date',
        dataIndex: 'shipment_pickup_date',
        key: 'shipment_pickup_date',
    },
    {
        title: 'Shipping ID',
        dataIndex: '_id',
        key: '_id',
    },
    {
        title: '',
        key: 'action',
        render: () => {

            return (
                <Space size="middle"
                    <Link to="/shipment-details" className='space-action-green'>View Details</Link>
                </Space>
            )
        },
    },
];

const Shipments: React.FC = () => {
    const [shipmentData, setShipmentData] = useState(null);
    const [customersData, setCustomersData] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        getSingleCustomer()
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        getSingleCustomerShipment()
    }, [])

    const getSingleCustomer = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        return makeAPICall({
            path: `get_single_customer/123456789`,
            method: "GET",
        })
          .then((data) => {
            setCustomersData(data);
            setLoading(false);
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            setLoading(false);
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    const getSingleCustomerShipment = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        return makeAPICall({
            path: `get_single_customer_shipments/123456789`,
            method: "GET"
        }).then((data) => {
            setShipmentData(data);
            console.log(data);
        }).catch((err) => {
            setLoading(false);
            console.log(err);

        })
    }

    return (
        <SiderLayout>
            <div className="site-layout-background" style={{ padding: "40px 40px", minHeight: 710 }}>
                <Link className='shipment-back' to="/">
                    <img src={ArrowLeft} alt="" />
                </Link>
                {loading ? "loading..." : (
                <>
                    <div className='shipment__container'>
                        <div className='shipment__container--image'>
                            <img src={data.Avatar} alt="" style={{ marginRight: 10 }} />
                            <div>
                                <p className='bold'>{first_name}</p>
                                <p>{email}</p>
                                <p>{phone}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span className='shipment__container--edit'>Edit</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='shipment__border'>
                        <div className='shipment-spacing'>
                            <button className='new-shipment'>Add New Shipment {" "} +</button>
                            <select className='shipment-select' name="" id="">
                                <option value="">Shipment Type</option>
                            </select>
                            <select className='shipment-select' name="" id="">
                                <option value="">Shipment Date</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div className='shipment-search'>
                            <form className="nosubmit">
                                <input className="nosubmit" type="search" placeholder="Search by shipment ID, Destination" />
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    </SiderLayout>
```

So I'm having these two api calls to be made on the same page. However I created two interface because both would definitely be needed on the it. But I don't really know how I can achieve that, because it is given an error message cannot find name data. So I brought it here for any person with an idea of it to help me out.

Comment: I have added the shipmentData to the dataSource={shipmentData} on the Table, but it still throws an additional error of Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'readonly SingleCustomerShipmentData[] | undefined'. Please I need any help I can get

Answer (score 0):

```
const [shipmentData, setShipmentData] = useState(null);
const [customersData, setCustomersData] = useState(null);
```

these shouldn't start as a null value. Because AntD Table requires an array to render.

```
const [shipmentData, setShipmentData] = useState([]);
const [customersData, setCustomersData] = useState([]);
```

should solve the problem you are facing.